# Sql query to get avaerage value between time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have this below data:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| date                | irradiance |
+---------------------+------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |          0 |
| 2016-03-15 07:00:00 |         35 |
| 2016-03-15 07:05:00 |         48 |
| 2016-03-15 07:10:00 |         63 |
| 2016-03-15 07:15:00 |         79 |
| 2016-03-15 07:20:00 |         93 |
| 2016-03-15 07:25:00 |        111 |
| 2016-03-15 07:30:00 |        130 |
| 2016-03-15 07:35:00 |        148 |
| 2016-03-15 07:40:00 |        168 |
| 2016-03-15 07:45:00 |        190 |
| 2016-03-15 07:50:00 |        209 |
| 2016-03-15 07:55:00 |        235 |
| 2016-03-15 08:00:00 |        253 |
| 2016-03-15 08:05:00 |        272 |
| 2016-03-15 08:10:00 |        298 |
| 2016-03-15 08:15:00 |        319 |
| 2016-03-15 08:20:00 |        338 |
| 2016-03-15 08:25:00 |        363 |
| 2016-03-15 08:30:00 |        382 |
| 2016-03-15 08:35:00 |        411 |
| 2016-03-15 08:40:00 |        430 |
| 2016-03-15 08:45:00 |        450 |
| 2016-03-15 08:50:00 |        475 |
| 2016-03-15 08:55:00 |        494 |
```

I need to get the average irradiance value between time intervals 7 to 7:55 and 8 to 8:55 . PLease let me know what is the sql query to get this ?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: `SELECT AVG(irradiance) FROM myTable WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-03-15 07:00:00' AND '2016-03-15 07:55:00'`

Comment: i am new to sql. I dont know how to write this query. can you assist?

Comment: Hi , incase i need to get the concurrent time intervals. for example 8 to 8:55 , 9 to 9:55 an so on .